# Pandas Correlation - Handling 0s on both columns

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, data-science, correlation

**Situation:** I'm working with a large dataframe, around 100 columns and around 2 million rows. The goal is to find the correlation between each column. But the dataset has a lot of 0 values in each row, so when I use `df.corr()`,  the result is not correct, because the correlation between two rows, lets suppose A and B, with lots of `(0, 0)` is different form `(x, y)`, for `x != 0 | y != 0`.

Like this:

```
#dataframe without zeros for both columns
df = pd.Dataframe([(.2, .3), (.1, .2), (.3, .6), (.6, .9), 
    (.5, .0), (.0, .5)], columns = ['dogs', 'cats'])
ρ = corr(dogs,cats) = 0.2482

#dataframe with lots of zeros for both columns
df = pd.Dataframe([(.2, .3), (.1, .2), (.3, .6), (.6, .9), 
    (.5, .0), (.0, .5), (.0, .0), (.0, .0), (.0, .0), (.0, .0)],
    columns = ['dogs', 'cats'])
ρ = corr(dogs,cats) = 0.5743

#dataframe with np.NaN instead of every zero
df = pd.Dataframe([(.2, .3), (.1, .2), (.3, .6), (.6, .9), 
    (.5, .0), (.0, .5), (.0, .0), (.0, .0), (.0, .0), (.0, .0)],
    columns = ['dogs', 'cats'])
df = df.replace(0, np.NaN)
ρ = corr(dogs,cats) = 0.9759
```

**Main Problem:** The use of NaN  when calculating the correlation in a pandas df implicates that it'll ignore all sets that have at least one zero, so the df becomes: `[(.2, .3), (.1, .2), (.3, .6), (.6, .9)]`.
I need to calculate the correlation without the (0, 0), but with `(0,y) & (x, 0)`, and currently the only possible way that i can figure is to build two for loops and iterate over every column...

Like this:

```
results = []
for (col_name_1, col_data_1) in df.iteritems():
    for (col_name_2, col_data_2) in df.iteritems():          
        res = pd.concat([col_data_1, col_data_2])

        #only get the rows that aren't (0,0)
        res = res[!((res[col_name_1] == 0) & (res[col_name_2] == 0))]

        #get the value from the correlation and save it
        corr = result.corr().stack()[1]
        results.append((col_name_1, col_data_2, corr,))
```

**EDIT**
Just to be clear, now when I use df.corr() without the for loops, it takes 1 minute. With the for loop presented above, the process started more than 30 min ago and still running. Maybe I should change to a numpy column of each df column to do the operation...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to achieve:

```
df[~((df.dogs==0.0)&(df.cats==0.0))].corr()
    dogs    cats
dogs    1.000000    0.248199
cats    0.248199    1.000000
```

or if you wish

```
rho = df[~((df.dogs==0.0)&(df.cats==0.0))].corr().iloc[1,0]
rho
0.24819888822736433
```

Comment: Not exactly. Although your answer is better than the method I use, and I appreciate that (thanks), what I really want is to know if there is a method, library, function, that handles this, without need to code it as I did.
Like a library that already ignores (0,0) to calculate it or a method that makes it less significant...

Comment: @edit: just to be clear, now when I use df.corr() without the for loops, it takes 1 minute. With the for loop presented above, the process started more than 30 min ago and still running. Maybe I should change to a numpy column of each df column to do the operation...

Comment: I'am not aware of readily available method. Though I must admit I do not know everything. If this answer adds some value to you you're free to accept or upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! It works way better when I change the df to a numpy array to make the calculations. It changed from more than 1 hour with pandas to less than 1 min with numpy. **It's important to highlight** that with pandas.corr() it works pretty fast because pandas is built on top of NumPy. The problem was all those data manipulations to calculate the correlation for every pair.

Final code:

```
corr_np = corr_df.to_numpy()  
correlations = []

print('{} - Calculating Correlation'.format(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))

for col_1 in range(corr_np.shape[-1]):
    for col_2 in range(corr_np.shape[-1]):
        if col_2 > col_1: #to not calculate duplicates, eg. (A, G) (G, A)
            # to remove rows when both are 0, eg. (0, 0)
            numpy_col_1 = corr_np[~((corr_np[:,col_1]==.0) & (corr_np[:,col_2]==.0)),col_1]
            numpy_col_2 = corr_np[~((corr_np[:,col_1]==.0) & (corr_np[:,col_2]==.0)),col_2]
            cor = np.corrcoef(numpy_col_1, numpy_col_2)[-1,0]
            correlations.append(cor)

print('{} -\t Finished'.format(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
```

Output:

```
2019-10-24 hh:19:50 - Calculating Correlation
2019-10-24 hh:20:30 -    Finished
```